# Multiple Comparisons Problem in Control Charts

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, quality-control

I have been taught control charts (or Shewhart charts) as a statistical tool to detect processes which are *out of control*. One particular case was by taking $k$ samples of size $n$ from a process over different times and performing a Null Hypothesis Significance Test on each of their means at a significance level $\alpha$ by way of the z.test making use of the Central Limit Theorem.

I give a graphical example of this procedure below, where the area between the Upper Control Limit and the Lower Control Limit is the Acceptance Region for each test.

[image: Example of Control Chart]

For simplicity's sake, every sample came from a Standard Normal distribution and has size $n=10$. Furthermore, let's assume the population standard deviation $\sigma=1$ and the normality of the random variables was known beforehand, so an exact z.test on the Null Hypothesis $H_0:\mu_0=0$ at significance level $\alpha=0.05$ was conducted on each of the samples.

In this example, two of the sample means ended outside of the Control Limits, which is not rare even in this case where the Null Hypothesis is true since the Family-Wise Error Rate for 20 independent tests at significance level $\alpha=0.05$ is $1-(1-0.05)^{20}\approx 0.6415$.

By virtue of this example, it seems to me that control charts suffer from a multiple comparisons problem since the probability of making a Type I Error grows with the number of samples tested. However, control charts found in common literature use fixed control limits for any number of samples $k$ such as $3\sigma$ (which would correspond to $\alpha\approx 0.0027$) and I have seldom found any corrections applied to the Control Limits of control charts to account for the number of samples.

This issue is further aggravated when applying additonal *rules* such as declaring the process out of control if two or more points are more than 2 standard deviations away from the center line. These rules are translated onto this framework as additional tests performed on the same data, which increase the probability of making a Type I Error even higher.

**My question is:** Under the assumption that we would like to keep the probability of making a Type I Error under control (hence the Null Hypothesis Significance Testing framework), should any adjustments (such as the Bonferroni correction for the Family-Wise Error Rate or the Benjamini–Hochberg procedure for the False Discovery Rate) be applied to the significance level of each test when making a control chart or am I missing something?